# Divs inside Div with overflow property of css

Tags: css, html

I am developing a html page in which there is a div tag and inside that div tag there is a multiple div tags one by one, inside that every div tags there are also some div tags

for example

```
<div>
     <div class=wrap>
           <div class="child" style="width:30%"></div>
           <div class="child" style="width:30%"></div>   
           <div class="child" style="width:40%"></div>
    </div>

    <div class=wrap>
           <div class="child" style="width:10%"></div>
           <div class="child" style="width:50%"></div>   
           <div class="child" style="width:40%"></div>
    </div>


     <div class=wrap>
           <div class="child" style="width:70%"></div>
           <div class="child" style="width:30%"></div>   

    </div>


    <div class=wrap>
            <div class="child" style="width:100%"></div>
    </div>


    <div class=wrap>

           <div class="child" style="width:80%"></div>
           <div class="child" style="width:10%"></div>   
           <div class="child" style="width:10%"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

my expected result is

```
|------30------|------30------|---------40----------|
|--10--|---------40---------|----------50-----------|
|-----------------70-----------------|------30------|
|------------------------100------------------------|
|-------------------80----------------|--10--|--10--|
```

BUT THE ACTUAL RESULT I GOT

```
|------30------|------30------|
---------40----------|
|--10--|---------40---------|
----------50-----------|
|-----------------70-----------------|
------30------|
|------------------------100------------------------|
|-------------------80----------------|--10--|
--10--|
```

That mean the child div tags when occupy 100% area of parent div tag it overflows and comes in new line but i want that div tag horizontal (if belong same parent div)

I tried and used overflow property of div tag as overflow:hidden but it hide the next div tag which might overflows

below are my css classs
CSS Code:

```
.child
{
 float:left;
height:50px;
position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-bottom:1px solid #46464f;
border-right:1px solid #46464f;

}

.wrap {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;

    border-top: 1px solid #46464f;
    border-left: 1px solid #46464f;
}
```

please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

now define `box-sizing`  in your `.child` **class** because u define **border** `left` or `top`

than your **child** `with` is **calculated** this `50%+1`

```
.child{
box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

***[Live Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/XsUtGrqw)***

more about ***[box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)***

Comment: You should place properties with prefixes before the main property. With your css new webkit browers and firefox will use old vendor prefix property instead of box-sizing.

Answer (score 2):

Your left and right borders each add 1px to the total width. This is not too big a deal for the `.wrap` elements, but for the `.child` elements it makes them not all fit in one row, since they each have that extra 1px width.

Here's your layout using `outline` (which doesn't add width) to show where the child elements are: http://jsfiddle.net/tWESq/

You'll have to remove the left and right borders. As a workaround, you might have to add another inner div to each `.child` element and set the border on that instead. [If you can use](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing) the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing) property, that would also be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have got spaces between some divs. Try to delete all spaces like this

```
<div class="child" style="width:30%"></div><div class="child" style="width:30%"></div><div class="child" style="width:40%"></div>
```

or maybe it's because

```
border-right:1px solid #46464f;
```

try to delete it.